# Why does it make intuitive sense for two mutually exclusive events to not be independent?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

One way to check whether two events are independent is with the formula P(A&B) = P(A)*P(B). If this holds, the two events are independent (to my knowledge).

Now if A and B are mutually exclusive events, and P(A)>0 and P(B)>0, then P(A&B) = 0 ≠ P(A)*P(B), and thus the events are considered dependent. Why does this make intuitive sense? It seems to me that if we have two events that are mutually exclusive, then almost by definition one does not affect the other, and so they should be independent. Where is my reasoning going wrong?

Comment: For A and B to be independent means that knowing A happened gives you no clue about whether or not B happened. If A and B are mutually exclusive, and you know that A happened, then you have a huge clue about whether B happened -- in fact, you now know for sure that B did not happen.

Comment: A person is either alive or dead, these events are mutually excluse. Does your knowledge of either affect the probability of the other event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two events are mutually exclusive, then one of them occurring forces the other not to occur. That is totally incompatible with independence, in which (knowledge of) one of them occurring does not affect the probability of the other occurring.

Answer (score 3):

Mutually exclusive means "if one happens, the other doesn't". Which means that knowing something about whether one event happens gives you information about whether the other did.

Rolling a 3 on a die and flipping heads on a coin are independent events. They don't affect each other, you can't gain information about the result of one from knowing something about the result of the other. If I roll a 3 on the die and then ask you the probability that the coin flipped heads, you can safely ignore the die roll and tell me that it's 50%.

Flipping heads on a coin and flipping tails on the same toss are mutually exclusive (and, to some approximation, exhaustive) events. If I tell you the coin flipped tails, then ask you what the probability is that it flipped heads, you're going to give me a completely different answer to before.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion seems to be about what "affect" means.  One way that $A$ can affect $B$ is by making it impossible for $B$ to happen when $A$ happens.

Answer (score 1):

If two events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then they cannot happen at the same time.  Thus, if event $A$ occurs, then it "affected" $B$ which cannot now occur.

Answer (score 1):

Mutually exclusive events are those whose union is the empty set; and thus is an impossible event.

- If $A,B$ are mutually exclusive, then $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0$.

Independent events are those whose joint probability is the product of their marginal probabilities.

- If $A,B$ are independent, then and only then $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B)$.

What then is obviously required for two mutually exclusive events to be independent?   At least one event must be a null set (have zero probability measure).   Otherwise, two mutually exclusive events are dependent.

Intuitively this is the case because, the occurrence of some event $A$ *depends* on the non-occurrence of any mutually exclusive event $B$ (when both have non-zero measure of occurring).

- $\mathsf P(A\mid B)=0 \;,\, \mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement) = \mathsf P(A)/\mathsf P(B^\complement)$